# Dim a Window from Variable

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net

I am creating a window that uses a UserControl to load icons onto a screen. Once I click those icons, the goal is to open the appropriate Window or Page in WPF.

Here´s my problem:

```
Sub openApp(obj As Object, e As MouseButtonEventArgs)

    Dim app As Object = TryCast(e.Source, UserControl.ucMenuAppIcon).Name

End Sub
```

Normally here, i would have some code like: Dim windows as new Window bla bla. But now I need to use the "app" variable as my window name. How do I do this, without make a really long if function to check against all apps in my system?

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Harshana, but it wasn't quite what I was looking for. This is a code that will work well for WPF. For those still with Winforms (please use Forms instead of Windows).

```
Dim objForm As Window
    Dim FormInstanceType As Type

    Dim appStr As String = "AplicationNameSpace_GoesHere." + TryCast(e.Source, UserControl.ucMenuAppIcon).Name

    Try
        FormInstanceType = Type.GetType(appStr, True, True)

        objForm = CType(Activator.CreateInstance(FormInstanceType), Window)
        objForm.Show()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

This code will basically take your string, and open a corresponding window with the exact same name. if window with same name doesn't exist, it will just throw an exception error.

Answer (score 0):

In the mainwindow code as follows,

```
Private Sub btn_details_click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim window__1 As Window = Window.GetWindow(Me)
    window__1.Opacity = 0.3
    Dim popUpwindow As New PopUpWindow("name", "x", "y")
    popUpwindow.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

then add a constructor as follows in PopUpWindow,

```
Function PopUpWindow(name As String, x As Double, y As Double) As [Public]
    InitializeComponent()

    Dim window__1 As Window = Window.GetWindow(Me)
    window__1.Width = x
    window__1.Height = y
End Function
```

Comment: ok, but i need for full sized windows. Plus I need to pass the name somehow. The code is to be used for a MainMenu where the app icons are loaded dynamically. Once the user clicks on an icon, it should open that window. I need to pass the name and then dimensionalize that window. how can I do this??

Comment: I'll Edit My Answer. you have to create a new constructor on the pop up window.